# Can I Use Asp.Net as front end and MSSQL as back end?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I have an specific requirement of my client. he wants me to develop an web based application for him which will be hosted on Ubuntu. I am having experience with Asp.Net and MSSQL.

Can I use this? if yes, anyone please help me, how can i do this?

Comment: Has your client explained to you the rationale of going for an open source solution for the OS and then sticking to proprietary software for the services? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but of course I don't know your use case. It would be interesting to know.

Comment: @hmayag ASP.net MVC is 100% open sourced by microsoft. However MSSQL is not.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent technology to .net on linux is the mono framework. I am not aware of any  database back-ends that can directly replace mssql (i.e. that are open sourse versions of it). Of course there are quite a few open source database systems available on linux (mysql and postgresql to name a few) that are at least as potent if not superior to mssql in a wide variety of use cases.